# Docker running composer in startup script, composer never runs

Tags: docker, composer-php, supervisord

I've got a docker container which is effectively a LAMP stack. I'm using supervisord for managing the processes.

I can execute a bash script when the container starts, but I can't get the script to run composer.

My simple script

```
#!/bin/bash

git clone https://github.com/[..project..].git /var/www/
wait

composer update -d /var/www/
wait

# Just here to test if we make it this far...
touch /var/www/test

exit
```

And the section from supervisord.conf that is responsible for running it

```
[program:deploy]
command=bash deploy.sh
directory=/usr/local/bin/
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=false
environment=PATH="/usr/bin"
redirect_stderr=true
```

This clones the repository successfully, and touches the test file but skips over running composer. If I open a shell in the container I can successfully execute the script manually.

Any advice on how to solve this?

Comment: Seems the issue is composer can't be found when the script is run from supervisord....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with my supervisord config.

The correct config is

```
[program:deploy]
command=bash /usr/local/bin/deploy.sh
autostart=true
autorestart=false
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/composer/run.log
```